# How can I query my Azure container app logs AWS style?

Tags: azure, azure-log-analytics, azure-container-apps

I'm trying to query my container app logs that are from a NodeJS http server which logs json lines.

Currently I can query my json logs this way

```
ContainerAppConsoleLogs_CL
| where Log_msg_s == "request completed"
and Log_req_url_s has "/my/path"
and Log_req_method_s has "GET"
```

Here are my problems:

- I really don't like the conversion to some prefixed column. What if my logs have very diverse objects in them? How many columns can Azure create before it implodes?
- How can I query AWS CloudWatch style? Have some platform columns like @containerName or something, but by default I'm querying my logs, like here would be `msg = 'request completed' and req.url = 'xxx'`.
- How can I view my json log in a standard, formatted way like AWS does? right now my eyes are exploding because every nested path is a long ass column, plus there are many Azure columns that I'm not interested in (I know I can project fields, but that is not solving my problem).

Side question: my ContainerAppConsoleLogs table does not have any log on it, why is that? What's the difference with _CL?

Thank you!